# IBM Bluemix: Serving Angular with NodeJs in Production Devops

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, devops-services

I have an Angular app, it is served via a small NodeJs app.

I have a Jenkins Job who build my app and package it.

The output artifacts are a `dist` directory with the angular app and the node `app.js` file to do the serving.

I want now to take those artifacts to push them to bluemix.

The thing is :

- You need a `package.json` file for cloudfoundry to detect the nodeJs buildpack
- When you have a `package.json` bluemix/cloudfoundry(?) execute `npm install / build / test` commands

I already have a builded application, so I simply need to call *node app.js* for my app to be served. And in terms of devops I would prefer to keep the Only Build Once good practice in place.

My current bypass is to have an empty `package.json` to trick bluemix.

So, I want to know if It's possible to deploy a node application on bluemix without needing a `package.json` ?

Or at least disable the `npm` commands ?

I just want bluemix/cloudfoundry(?) to do a `node app.js`

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways (manifest.yml and command line) to target a specific build pack.  This webpage documents the model https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node/node-tips.html#discovery

You may also want to consider shrinkwrap (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap) for locking the versioning of your dependencies.

If you combine these two, I think it gets you closer to your goals.